Angular CDK Menu wont open next to menu trigger
I am trying to learn to use the Angular CDK and create some components in my app.
The app uses just tailwindCSS and daisyUI plugin for elements.
I'm trying to just get the basic menu with standalone trigger to display, then style it with tailwind.
However, no matter how I add it to any of my views, the menu displays detached from the trigger button. Usually in the bottom-left of the page or parent container.
Is there something I am missing, or a possible conflict between tailwind classes that is causing this behavior?
This is the component when shown on the page with nothing else rendered:

This is it with one element added:

And this is it when inside a flex container with justify-center:


Looks like the missing piece is you need to add the overlay-prebuilt.css import to your stylesheet
@import "@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt";

Because I am not using any @angular/material packages, components or stylesheets, this was not imported, and it is not clearly stated in their examples or Getting Started docs that this would be required for proper formatting.
It is found in the Overlay | Getting Started, which is confusing because if you're lookin at the Menu docs, there is no mention of this setup being a prerequisite.
Hope this saves others some time who might face this same issue.
